# Why does Rust hello world try to read /proc and /sys

Tags: compilation, rust

I have the need of running a Rust executable (made with `cargo build --release`) inside a chroot. Normally, I just copy the files reported by ldd

```
$ldd hello_world_rust
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffef48c6000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3224c3e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3224a21000)
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3224819000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3224603000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3224261000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3224e42000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3223f5d000)
```

But my Rust programs crashes when run inside the jail

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)` (left: `2`, right: `0`)', /build/rust/src/rustc-1.1.0/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:204
fatal runtime error: Could not unwind stack, error = 5
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

When checking things with strace (inside the jail) I noticed the following

```
strace -e file hello_world_rust
.... 14 lines of loading dynlibs cut
readlink("/etc/je_malloc.conf", 0x7fff7c2ed380, 4096) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/cpuinfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I believe the crash occurs because there are no /proc and /sys inside the chroot.

Is my belief correct? If so, why are they necessary? Is there a way I can compile my rust program so that it does not need /sys and /proc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a [known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22642). According to Alex Crichton:

> it looks like [the failure in question](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f0f7ca27de6b4e03f30012656dad270cda55a363/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs#L89) is our detection of the stack start of the main thread in setting up the first guard page. I forget how reliable it is that linux sets up a guard page for us, and it would be tough to remove for now at least.